# How to parse a complex JSON String got from a webservice response with GSON in Java?

Tags: json, gson

Hello Everybody,

```
      I am new to Json/Gson. I have already looked all around the internet for help, but I     have seen nothing so similar to what I need to parse. So I am posting here, any help will be appreciated.
```

I am receiving as a response from the webservice I am calling this Json String:

```
        Json String = {"courses":[{"links":         [{"href":"https://xp.student.com/courses/6364145","rel":"self","title":"course"}]},         {"links":    [{"href":"https://xp.student.com/courses/6364143","rel":"self","title":"course"}]},
        {"links":    [{"href":"https://xp.student.com/courses/6364144","rel":"self","title":"course"}]}]}
```

I have already done code up to the point where I get the "Json String":

```
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(reader);
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     Course courses = new Gson().fromJson(in,Course.class);
```

I have also created the following classes:

```
        import ccSample.Type.Course.Link;

        public class Course {

        public Link links[];

        } 

        public class Link{
        public String href;
        public String rel;
        public String title;
        public String getHref() {
        return href;
        }
       public void setHref(String href) {
       this.href = href;
        }
        public String getRel() {
        return rel;
        }
        public void setRel(String rel) {
        this.rel = rel;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
        return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        }

        }





         but I am just getting a null courses object and do not know what I am missing,     any suggestions corrections are welcome!

    Thank you very much :)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's layers of an onion.  Peel them one at a time.  You can use the `instanceof` operator and/or `getClass().getName()` method calls to figure out what you have at each step and double-check it's as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, gotcha..

You need another wrapper for the courses since in the reply its contained in another json object

```
    public class Reply {
    private Course[] courses;

    public void setCourses(Course[] courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public Course[] getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
}
```

And then

`Reply reply = new Gson().fromJson(in,Reply.class);`

Should do it :)